# Latex Exam Class: Line width for answers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

I am using latex exam class for short questions which provide lines for answers. The following code codes gives me lines for answers which span the full width of the page. I want to control the width of these lines so that I can reduce them according to my choice (1 inch, 2in etc.)

```
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question What is your name? \fillwithlines{3cm}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

As an example, this is what I get with the existing code:

[image]

Whereas I want something the following:
[image]

I would appreciate for any help in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: If you use multicols, paracol or a minipage, the lines will reduce to fit the column width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using a `minipage` environment is probably the simplest solutions. If you're doing this a lot you can create a `minipage` version of the `\fillwithlines` command. This takes an optional width argument which defaults to `\linewidth` if not used.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Fillwithlines}{O{\linewidth}m}{
\par\begin{minipage}{#1}
\fillwithlines{#2}
\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question What is the answer to this question?

\Fillwithlines[3in]{1in}

\question What is the answer to this question?

\Fillwithlines{1in}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question, and you didn't give enough of a sample document to test. I'm happy to modify this answer to account for the revised question, but please edit the question giving a compilable sample document like the one I gave in my answer that I can play with.

Comment: Sorry Alan. I was writing my whole comment and accidently pressed entered which posted the comment. Here is the full comment:
Thanks Alan. There is one issue that I am running into. Since I wanted the solution to print as well, so I had to use "\begin{solutionorlines}" environment as follows and I am wondering how to tweak your suggested solution to this case?

Write first three aphabets.
\begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
 \begin{color}{red} 
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item a
   \item b
   \item c
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{color}
\end{solutionorlines}

Comment: @Tash As I said, edit your question, with a complete minimal document that can be used rather than giving code in the comment.

Comment: OK. Will do that now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Alan. Since your solution is the best for this question so we keep this thread as is (instead of confusing those who see this later, I think I should post my problem as a new question because as it is kind of different. What do you say?

Comment: Either would work I think. If you do ask a new question, make sure that you include a reference and link to this question too.

Comment: Hi Alan. Here is link to related but new question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/679740/44006

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was in the new question, link to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This code replaces the hard-wired length of the lines (`\hsize`) with a custom length (`\linelength`) that can be set before a question.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{exam}
    
%**************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlength{\linelength}
\setlength{\linelength}{\hsize}% default length
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\do@fillwithlines}
{\hsize}{\linelength}{}{}
\makeatother
%****************************************

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\linelength}{1.5in}% choose the line length <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question What is your name? \fillwithlines{3cm}
                    
        \setlength{\linelength}{2.5in}% choose the line length <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question What is your name? \fillwithlines{3cm}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```