# Latex Exam Class: custom Line width for exam class "solutionorlines" environment

Tags: exam, width, line, custom

I am using "solutionorlines" environment of latex exam class for short questions (with solution) which provide lines for answers. The following code codes gives me lines for answers which span the full width of the page. I want to control the width of these lines so that I can reduce them according to my choice (1 inch, 2in etc.). Since I have already written many questions, it will be nice to have a document wide solution as well.

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\printanswers
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question List down three alphabets.
    \begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
    \begin{enumerate}
          \item a
          \item b
          \item c 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{solutionorlines}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

As an example, this is what I get with the existing code:
[image]

Whereas I want something the following:

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482459/dynamic-spacing-in-exam-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `\linefill` macro (no idea if the exam class also uses this for other things, so use at your own risk):

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\printanswers

\renewcommand\linefill{\leavevmode\rule{.4\textwidth}{\linefillthickness}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question List down three alphabets.
    \begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
    \begin{enumerate}
          \item a
          \item b
          \item c 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{solutionorlines}
\end{questions}

\begin{questions}
    \question List down three alphabets.
    \renewcommand\linefill{\leavevmode\rule{.8\textwidth}{\linefillthickness}}
    \begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
    \begin{enumerate}
          \item a
          \item b
          \item c 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{solutionorlines}
\end{questions}

\begin{questions}
    \question List down three alphabets.
    \begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
    \begin{enumerate}
          \item a
          \item b
          \item c 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{solutionorlines}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. That worked fine. Is it possible to override this document wide width for some questions which need more space?

Comment: @Tash You can make the changes locally, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Samcarter. It works fine.

Comment: @Tash You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put question inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\printanswers
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  
  \begin{minipage}{2in}
    \question List down three alphabets.\\
    \begin{solutionorlines}[3cm]
      \begin{enumerate}
          \item with a very long line of text
          \item b
          \item c 
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{solutionorlines}
  \end{minipage}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```